# Recursive mapping function haskell

Tags: haskell, recursion, mapping

My goal is to write a recursive function that uses the mapping function to generate a set of lists of integers that are ultimately generated from an initial list of integers.

To help me understand what my coding needs to do, I set `lst0` as my initial list of integers, then used `lst0` to make `lst1`,and `lst1` to make `lst2`,and so on and so forth.

```
lst0 = [1,25,100] 

lst1 =  map (\x -> 0 + x) lst0

lst2 =  map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) lst0) lst1 

lst3 =  map (\z -> map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) lst0) z) lst2 

lst4 =  map (\w -> map (\z -> map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) lst0) z) w) lst3
```

Then I rewrote the above lists as functions that take as input the previous list/funcition. They all work fine (e.g., `list4 lst3` which is short for `list4 $ list3 $ list2 $ list1 $ list0`).

```
list0 = [1,25,100] 

list1 prev =  map (\x -> 0 + x) prev

list2 prev =  map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) list0) prev

list3 prev =  map (\z -> map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) list0)z) prev

list4 prev =  map (\w -> map (\z -> map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) list0)z) w) prev
```

I then rewrote each function with the previous function in it to get the below functions. These also work just fine.

```
list0' = [1,25,100] 

list1' =  map (\x -> 0 + x) list0'

list2' prev =  map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) list0') prev

list3' prev =  map (\z -> list2' z) prev

list4' prev =  map (\w -> list3' w) prev
```

Yet when I try to condense all of the above functions into a recursive `foo` function below, I get the following error about `(foo (n-1) initlst) z`. The `n` is the depth of the game tree I am building and `initlst` will be `lst0` (that is `[1,25,100]`).

```
foo n initlst
 | n == 1    = map (\x -> 0 + x) initlst
 | n == 2    = map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) initlst) $ foo 1 initlst
 | otherwise = map (\z -> (foo (n-1) initlst) z) $ foo (n-1) initlst
```

The error message is the following and it references this part of the `foo` function: `(foo (n-1) initlst) z`:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a1 -> a1’ with actual type ‘[a1]’
Relevant bindings include
  z :: a1 (bound at BuildTreesQ3.lhs:61:24)
  initlst :: [a1] (bound at BuildTreesQ3.lhs:58:9)
  foo :: a -> [a1] -> [a1] (bound at BuildTreesQ3.lhs:58:3)
The function ‘foo’ is applied to three arguments,
but its type ‘a -> [a1] -> [a1]’ has only two
In the expression: (foo (n - 1) initlst) z
In the first argument of ‘map’, namely
  ‘(\ z -> (foo (n - 1) initlst) z)’
```

Any insights into what I'm missing will be very much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't apply `lst3 w`, because `lst3` is not a function. It is a list. Similarly, you cannot apply `(foo (n-1) lst0) w`, because `(foo (n-1) lst0)` is a list, not a function.  This is what the compiler is telling you in the error message.

Comment: What is your desired output? I'm struggling to understand what you want your code to do.

Comment: The problem is that your code is returning arbitrary nested lists. 
lst0 = [1,25,100] 
lst1 = [1,25,100]
lst2 = [[2,26,101],[26,50,125],[101,125,200]]
lst3 = [[[3,27,102],[27,51,126],[102,126,201]],[[27,51,126],[51,75,150],[126,150,225]],[[102,126,201],[126,150,225],[201,225,300]]]
Try capturing this arbitrary nested lists in data structure.

Comment: what's going to be the first element? it's going to be an infinitely nested list, won't it? it's not expressible in Haskell.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I see what you're saying. If `lst3` were rewritten as `lst3' prev =  map (\z -> map (\y -> map (\x -> y + x) lst0) z) prev`, then `lst3' w` would work, right?

Comment: @4castle the desired output of lists is what you see in the comment by keep_learning. All the sub-lists are made up of adding the same value to [1, 25, 100]. So if you added 1 to each one you get [2, 26, 101]. If adding 25 you get [26, 50, 125]. The integers from earlier lists become the number added to [1, 25, 100].

Comment: @keep_learning Actually the lists that are generated follow systematically from a recursive pattern. I explained this pattern in my comment to 4castle. I'm not well versed in Haskell and don't know how I would generate these lists through data structures. I'll check into this, though.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr The first list is `[1,25,100]`. I explained how the lists are made in my comment to 4castle's comment (see above). The list won't be an infinitely nested list since it will begin with a value for n (= the number of levels to the game tree) and subtract one at each iteration, then when n = 1 it outputs lst1 (which is made from adding zero to each element of `[1, 25, 100]`).